# ValueError: Please move the function into the main module body to use migrations

Tags: django, python-3.x, python-2.7, django-models, django-migrations

**The error that I am trying to Fix**

> **ValueError**: Could not find function func in posts.models.
>   Please note that due to Python 2 limitations, you cannot serialize unbound method functions (e.g. a method declared and used in the same class body). Please move the function into the main module body to use migrations.
>   For more information, see https:
>   //docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/migrations/#serializing-values

**Intro:** I am using Django==1.11.20 and Ubuntu 18.04. My python version is 3.6.7 When I do in my Django project in the

```
(venv)some_path$ python --version
Python 3.6.7
```

However when I do the same in my Ubuntu terminal I get

```
marco@VB:~$ python --version
Python 2.7.15rc1

marco@VB:~$ python3 --version
Python 3.6.7
```

**About my project:** I have the below models

```
def upload_name (user_fld='user', prefix=None):
    def func(instance, fname):
        #return os.path.join(prefix, fname) if prefix else fname
        attrs = user_fld.split('.')
        user = instance
        print ("Getattr %s %s" % (attrs, user))
        try:
            for attr in attrs:
                user = getattr(user, attr)
        except:
            username = 'anon'
        else:
            username = user.username

        print ("Upload name** %s, %s" % (instance.pk, username))
        # Extract the raw fname
        fparts = fname.split('.')
        base = fparts[0]
        try:
            atoms = base.split("_")
            ts = datetime.strptime('_'.join(atoms[-7:]), "%Y_%m_%d_%H_%M_%S_%f")
            ousername = atoms[-8]
            base = '_'.join(atoms[:-8])
        except:
            # Any exception in handling this means it wasn't already equipped with our
            # extension so add it on
            pass

        ts = datetime.now()
        fname = '%s_%s_%s%s' % (base, username, ts.strftime("%Y_%m_%d_%H_%M_%S_%f"),
                                ('.%s' % '.'.join(fparts[1:])) if len(fparts) > 1 else '')
        return os.path.join(prefix, fname) if prefix else fname

    return func

class Post(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='posts')
    title = models.CharField(max_length=250, unique=True)
    slug = models.SlugField(allow_unicode=True, unique=True, max_length=500)
    post_image = models.ImageField(null=True, blank=True, upload_to=upload_name())

class Prep (models.Model): #(Images)
    post = models.ForeignKey(Post, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='post_prep')
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to=upload_name('post.user', 'images/'), blank=True, null=True, default='')
    image_title = models.CharField(max_length=100, default='')
```

Trying to figure out how to add the deconstruct() method

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/migrations/#adding-a-deconstruct-method

[image]

> Trying @RaydelMiranda solution

```
def upload_name_factory(instance, fname, user_fld='user', prefix=None):
    attrs = user_fld.split('.')
    user = instance
    print("Getattr %s %s" % (attrs, user))
    try:
        for attr in attrs:
            user = getattr(user, attr)
    except:
        username = 'anon'
    else:
        username = user.username

    print("Upload name** %s, %s" % (instance.pk, username))
    # Extract the raw fname
    fparts = fname.split('.')
    base = fparts[0]
    try:
        atoms = base.split("_")
        ts = datetime.strptime('_'.join(atoms[-7:]), "%Y_%m_%d_%H_%M_%S_%f")
        ousername = atoms[-8]
        base = '_'.join(atoms[:-8])
    except:
        # Any exception in handling this means it wasn't already equipped with our
        # extension so add it on
        pass

    ts = datetime.now()
    fname = '%s_%s_%s%s' % (base, username, ts.strftime("%Y_%m_%d_%H_%M_%S_%f"),
                            ('.%s' % '.'.join(fparts[1:])) if len(fparts) > 1 else '')
    return os.path.join(prefix, fname) if prefix else fname


upload_name = partial(upload_name_factory, user_fld='user', prefix=None)
```

Comment: The problem is that Django works with a *reference*, and you can not thus use such wrapper-method.

Comment: @PatrickArtner I am not mixing them. Ubuntu 18.04 comes default with Python 2.7. My Project is using 3.6 I dont think It should be an issue as my project shows 3.6. I don't know why 2.7 is getting involved

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem Is there something I can fix to make this work. I was using to save my images with names like image_name_admin_2019_04_28_02_08_32_204448.jpg

Comment: @PatrickArtner I added a image above. I believe it is using 3.6. Plus the pycharm terminal says 3.6 too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see what you want to do, you want to be able to reuse the function you pass to `upload_to` being able to customize the `user_fld` and the `prefix` params.

So, you already know you have to move the function to the main module body. How to do that and keep your idea of reusability?

Partial functions.

```
from django.db import models
from functools import partial

def upload_name_factory(instance, filename, user_fld='user', prefix=None):
    attrs = user_fld.split('.')
    user = instance
    # ...

upload_name = partial(upload_name_factory, user_fld='user', prefix="/some/prefix/")

class Foo(models.Model):
    f = models.FileField(upload_to=upload_name)
```

Read more about partials [here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functools.html#).

Comment: I have tried your solution in the top. Did I do it correct

Comment: No, just make the body of func the body of upload_name_factory, with this solution you don't need an inner function

Comment: I've edited the answer in order to give you a better idea

Comment: I have edited my code too see above in the question. Now I am getting the beow error `TypeError: upload_name_factory() missing 2 required positional arguments: 'instance' and 'fname'`

Comment: what about:  

def upload_name(instance, filename):
    return upload_name_factory(instance, filename, user_fld='user', prefix="/some/prefix/")